# Display progress bar for asynchronous request using JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, progress-bar

Instead of using ProgressBar plugin, I've used below script to display the progress bar for async. requests on the page. Could anyone provide feedback, if it is browser compatible, etc. I've raised this question on codereview last week but didn't get any response, so trying out here.

```
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="progress">
       <img src="@Url.Content("~/content/images/loading.gif")" />Loading...
    </div>
</div>

//displays progress bar
$('.overlay').ajaxStart(function () {
       $(this).css({ height: $(document).height(), width: $(document).width() }).show();
       $(this).find(".progress").css({ top: $(window).height() / 2, left: $(window).width() / 2 });
       }).ajaxStop(function () {
       $(this).hide();
});


.overlay
{
    position: fixed !important;
    position: absolute; /*ie6*/
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #000;
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
    opacity: 0.2;
    -moz-opacity: 0.2;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-opacity: 0.2;
    z-index: 10004;
    display: none;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=20); /*ie6*/
}
.overlay .progress
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10005;
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `width` and `height` functions returns zeros in IE 7-9(can't check older versions), so you may raplace `window` object with `this` object here:

```
$(this)
    .find('.progress')
    .css({
        top: $(this).height() / 2 + 'px',
        left: $(this).width() / 2  + 'px'
    });
```

You can use `this` for calculations, because your .overlay block has window's width and height.

Also, `@Url.Content` fails in modern browsers, why do you use it instead of setting path directly?